# Return a object but has the same function as array Javascript and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I was trying to pass a value

```
<SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults}/>
```

That is a state (and should return value as an array) to an attribute of a stateless component.

```
console.log(typeof(this.state.searchResults));
console.log(this.state.searchResults);
console.log(this.state.searchResults[1]);
```

It returns an object which was printed to the console looking the same as an array and I even can call it index and array default function, here is the result

[image]

I want to ask here is how I can change the object which should be an array into an array?

Comment: That is an array... `typeof` on arrays (which are just "special" objects) will give you `"object"`. Use `Array.isArray` to see if something is an array.

Comment: Reference for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, the array is an array. `typeof` can only return these possible [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Further, technically, an array *is* a type of object in JavaScript.

If you need to check if your state object is an array, try `Array.isArray()` or check the length such as `Array.length > 0`.